# .NET Core MVC display data upon loading of view

Tags: .net, .net-core, model-view-controller, .net-6.0

In a .NET 6 MVC, i have a controller that perform retrieval of login information from external system, and after a user login on 1.cshtml, it will redirect user to 2.cshtml which auto display user past transactions in a table, which i uses a foreach loop. The first part works fine but i cant get the 2.cshtml to work, is there any sample for such scenarios? The retrieval of login info and user past transactions are placed in a single controller file, the retrieval works fine but just cant get the data to display on 2.cshtml. Thanks in advance.

The 2.cshtml should display user past transaction automatically upon the page is loaded.

There is a foreach loop in 2.cshtml, which has null error (object to set to an instance):

```
@foreach (var r in Model)
                                {
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>@r.Title</td>
                                    </tr>
                                }
```

This is the Index method in 2Controller.cs:

```
public IActionResult Index()
    {
        List<dynamic> myList = new List<dynamic>();
        myList.Add("qwe");
        myList.Add("asd");


        return View(myList);
    }
```

And this is the login method in the main controller:

```
public IActionResult Login(string email, string password)
    {
        if (CallExternalSystem(email) == true)
        {
            HttpContext.Session.SetString("email", email);
            return View("2");
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.error = "Invalid Account";
            return View("Index");
        }
    }
```

Full code of 2.cshtml:

```
@model List<2>
@{
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="data-table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Col Header1</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @*<tr>
    <td>test data1</td>
    </tr>*@
        @foreach (var r in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@r.ToString()</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Could you provide the necessary code of what you have done, can't assist much with the info provided.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Yes edited with code..

Comment: please provide full code of 2.cshtml

Comment: please refer above newly provided full code of 2.cshtml..

Answer (score 0):

Your loop should only try to render `@r` because in your controller you are only adding strings.

```
@foreach (var r in Model)
{
   <tr>
      <td>@r</td>
   </tr>
}
```

Comment: i just tried this but it also has same error object reference not set to an instance

Comment: @stackoverflow in your view, try `@model List<dynamic>`